# Replacing a word in text using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I know how to do it by using this code

```
poem['sleepy'] = 'busy'
```

What the above object type called? Is it an Array?
How can I assign the poem to the first line of the text in order to replace the word "sleepy" that is sitting on that specific line?

Comment: This is a rather unnatural way of replacing strings. You should use gsub.

Comment: @vise, what is unnatural about replacing a string using a direct substitution, and why is `gsub` better?

Comment: @theTinMan, []= will raise an IndexError if the text in brackets isn't found, but gsub won't.  Not that []= is entirely without merit, but I think gsub is usually more flexible.

Comment: `gsub` doesn't have the same behavior as `[]=`. `sub` would. I find all three methods equally useful, but because they have different purposes I use them differently. Each is a very valid and useful tool to have in the toolbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not an array, it's [`String`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html)'s [`[]=`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D) method. If you want to only replace on a certain line, you can split the poem string and get an array by using the [`split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) method:

```
lines = poem.split("\n")
```

You could then make the replacement on the line you wish:

```
lines[3]["sleepy"] = "busy"
```

And then you can use [`Array`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html)'s [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-join) method to join the `Array` into a `String` again:

```
poem = lines.join("\n")
```

Comment: Well done thank you. in this case poem = the text file i have?

Comment: @user1556385, `poem` is the string variable you referred to in the question.